# Extending position absolute div outside overflow hidden div

Tags: html, css, overflow, css-position

I've haven't done css in several month so I might miss something simple, but whatever the solution is, I couldn't figure it out. So here is the problem.

Here is simplified version of my code:

```
<div id="wrapper" style="position: fixed; overflow: hidden; height: 100%; width: 200px;">
  <div id="test" style="position: absolute; margin-left: -200px;"></div>
</div>
```

So basically, I need the inner div test to extend 200px to the left, outside of outer div wrapper. The problem is that my wrapper is overflow:hidden and it won't allow to go outside.
I need it to stay overflow:hidden though, due to some js plugin I am using.

So is there any workarounds? 
Thanks

Comment: Can you share your code (or elaborate on the js plugin)?

Comment: Sorry, could't figure out at first

Comment: @doitlikejustin the plugin is niceScroll http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/

Answer (score 17):

Only option is to move that div outside of the `overflow:hidden` div.  You can't say *hide everything in this div that overflows -- except for this one div... let's make an exception*.

You can introduce one more layer in your hierarchy, whereby the inner div is overflow hidden and the outer div is not.  Then place that positioned element in the outer div.  A pseudo example would be:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner" style="overflow: hidden;">
    ....
  </div>

  <div class="abs-positioned">
  </div>
</div>
```

If by chance you had positioning on the old div with `overflow:hidden`, you would move that setting to the `outer` div, allowing things to position properly.

So the short answer: no solution will allow you to do what you want without either changing your CSS to not be `overflow:hidden` or without changing your markup.

Comment: Hmm, the reason I am trying to achieve that its because I have a <ul> inside my wrapper with many elements. And each element was supposed to have position relative with absolute positioned divs inside them. Not sure if I could explain... What I am saying is I can't take the absolute divs outside those lists...

Comment: Unfortunately those are your only two options -- change the overflow CSS rule, or change the markup to get around it.  Sorry!

Comment: The padding solution described is interesting, but it will also allow other elements to overflow into that padding area.  If that's ok, then consider it.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/15439038/1795053

Answer (score 15):

Expanding on Piyas De:

[an example](http://jsfiddle.net/5m3RE/1/)

Do note, that if the overflow hidden has

```
position: relative
```

then it will not work

[not working example](http://jsfiddle.net/5m3RE/)

Comment: The best answer

Answer (score 11):

Overflow hidden can actually be ignored if the following rules are observed:

- The overflowing child element has absolute positioning
- The parent with overflow hidden has static positioning
- A second parent wrapper with relative positioning is added

**HTML**

```
<div class="outer-wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="overflowed">(Overflowing the wrapper)</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.outer-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.overflowed {
  position: absolute;
}
```

**FIDDLE**
http://jsfiddle.net/vLsmmrz6/

Comment: Did you mean "A second parent wrapper with relative positioning is NOT added"? check this: http://jsfiddle.net/4pjz5srk/2/

Answer (score 3):

Something like -

```
<div id="textChange" style="overflow:hidden; padding-left:250px;">This is wrapper Div
This is wrapper Div<br/>
This is wrapper Div<br/>
<div id="textChange1" style="position:absolute;left:50; top: 50;">
This is inner div but extend 200px to the left<br/>
This is inner div but extend 200px to the left<br/>
This is inner div but extend 200px to the left<br/>
This is inner div but extend 200px to the left<br/>
This is inner div but extend 200px to the left<br/>
</div>
This is wrapper Div<br/>
This is wrapper Div<br/>
This is wrapper Div<br/>
</div>
```

May solve your problem.

See..whether it helps or not...

Answer (score -2):

Here's a fix that does not requires Javascript or moving anything. Just add a Parent wrapper with the width and height of #wrapper.

```
<div id="parent_wrapper" style="width:200px">
  <div id="wrapper" style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; height: 100%; width: 300px;">
    <div id="test" style="position: absolute; margin-left:200px;">Test</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please also see my live example: http://jsfiddle.net/ovjdqj4o/