# Absolute position and overflow hidden in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have set `overflow:hidden` for a container. I want to set absolute position for an element which is inside the container so that it is displayed outside the container, however overflow hidden is not letting it display.

It is important for me to use the `overflow:hidden` for the container, as I have lots of elements in the container. Is there anyway to make it work with the `overflow:hidden`?

The parent element of the `wrap` is the `body` tag and its hard to decide position according to that.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="box">
        <span>Left</span>
        <div class="main"></div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrap{
    width: 500px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    border: 1px solid green;
    overflow: hidden;    /*causes the problem */
}

.box{
    position: relative
}

.main{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: green;
}

span{
    position: absolute;
    left: -50px;
}
```

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/c55hS/

Comment: In short, no it isn't possible without changing your markup. See a detailed explanation here --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15438828/extending-position-absolute-div-outside-overflow-hidden-div

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837050/allow-specific-tag-to-override-overflowhidden
I think you can't.

Comment: Was writing up this question before realizing it's already answered. I have a simple fiddle that demonstrates how to achieve this, figured I'd share: http://codepen.io/tobek/pen/EGmxw

Answer (score 6):

As others have said it's not directly possible. There is a kind of workaround without having to change markup though - remove `position:relative` from `.box`, don't set `left` and `top` on the absolutely positioned element, but use negative margins to position the element where you want it instead.

It's necessary to remove `position:relative` from `.box`, because with it span is absolutely positioned relative to `.box` and so can't escape the `overflow:hidden` confines. Without it, it becomes absolutely positioned relative to the body and can then overlay `.box` using the negative margins.

It's critical not to set `top`, `bottom`, `left` or `right` though - this will cause it to be positioned the set distance from the body. If you don't set anything though (all `auto`), it's displayed in the correct inline position.

```
.wrap{
    width: 500px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

.box{

}

.main{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: green;
}

span{
    position: absolute;
    background:red;
    margin-left:-50px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c55hS/5/

Answer (score 2):

Slightly hacky, but this would work,

Adding an `.inner-wrap` inside your `.wrap` `div`

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="inner-wrap">
```

Then adding `left-padding` to the `.wrap` and shift the `border` down to `.inner-wrap`

```
.wrap{
    width: 500px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    overflow: hidden;    /*causes the problem */
    padding-left:50px;
}
.inner-wrap {
    border: 1px solid green; 
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/c55hS/6/)**

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so... I think you should just put your element outside the container...

Put your element here instead

```
 <div class="wrap">
   <div class="box">
     <span>Left</span>
     <div class="main"></div>
   </div>    
 </div>
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c55hS/4/)