# How to have absolutely positioned element inside a relative element not expand parent space, and also stretch outside of parent (z-index)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an autocomplete component that I am working with (downshift + react-virtualize) and the dropdown is:

1. Causing the parent div to resize.
2. Not breaking out of the parent container.

How do I get those to work?

Here is roughly what I have:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('.input')
const dropdown = document.querySelector('.dropdown')

dropdown.style.display = 'none'

input.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  e.stopPropagation()
  
  dropdown.style.display = 'block'
})

window.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  e.stopPropagation()
  
  dropdown.style.display = 'none'
})
```

```css
.form {
  z-index: 1000px; /* simulates the system I have in the app */
  background: pink;
}

.scroller {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 300px;
}

.autocomplete {
  position: relative;
}

.input {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  background: cyan;
}

.input-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
}

.icon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 0px;
}

.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2000px;
  background: green;
}

.list {
  height: 400px; /* really, I use JS to compute size */
}

.item {
  height: 100px;
  padding: 8px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.item:hover {
  background: #fcfcfc;
}

.stuff {
  z-index: 1500px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <div class="scroller">
    <div class="intro">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
    <div class="autocomplete">
      <div class="input-container">
        <input class="input" placeholder="Some text..." />
        <i class="icon">▾</i>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <div class="list">
          <div class="item">item 1</div>
          <div class="item">item 2</div>
          <div class="item">item 3</div>
          <div class="item">item 4</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="stuff">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I get the `dropdown` to fall over the parent, and not push the content down? The `z-index` values simulate the complex arrangement I have in my app so far.

The `scroller` has `overflow: auto` on it which seems like the main culprit, but I want that to be a separately scrollable area, just with the dropdown that pops out over it and doesn't push down content. "How to get position absolute to extend out of bounds of overflow auto?" Maybe https://front-back.com/how-to-make-absolute-positioned-elements-overlap-their-overflow-hidden-parent/ will help...

- [Extending position absolute div outside overflow hidden div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15438828/extending-position-absolute-div-outside-overflow-hidden-div)

Comment: `z-index: 2000px` Look closely, you put pixels in the z-index

Comment: Also since for `.scroller` you put `overflow: auto` it's content will be scrolled. Try showing the content that does not fit using: `overflow: visible`

Answer (score 0):

You should replace below style and test.

```
.form {
      z-index: 1000px; /* simulates the system I have in the app */
      background: pink;
    }
    
    .autocomplete {
     position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .input {
      display: block;
      width: 300px;
      background: cyan;
    }
    
    .input-container {
      position: relative;
      width: 300px;
    }
    
    .icon {
      position: absolute;
      right: 10px;
      top: 0px;
    }
    
    .dropdown {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 99;
      background: green;
      overflow-y: auto;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
    }
    
    .item {
      padding: 8px;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
    }
    
    .item:hover {
      background: #fcfcfc;
    }
    
    .stuff {
      z-index: 1500px;
      background: yellow;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, I went ahead and made changes I commented about.

I marked the places that had to be changed:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('.input')
const dropdown = document.querySelector('.dropdown')

dropdown.style.display = 'none'

input.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  e.stopPropagation()
  
  dropdown.style.display = 'block'
})

window.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  e.stopPropagation()
  
  dropdown.style.display = 'none'
})
```

```css
.form {
  z-index: 1000px; /* simulates the system I have in the app */
  background: pink;
}

.scroller {
  overflow: visible; /* <-- HERE */
  height: 300px;
}

.autocomplete {
  position: relative;
}

.input {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  background: cyan;
}

.input-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
}

.icon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 0px;
}

.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2000; /* <-- HERE */
  // background: green; /* <-- HERE (moved to .list) */
}

.list {
  height: 400px; /* really, I use JS to compute size */
  background: green; /* <-- HERE (added) */
}

.item {
  height: 100px;
  padding: 8px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.item:hover {
  background: #fcfcfc;
}

.stuff {
  z-index: 1500px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <div class="scroller">
    <div class="intro">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
    <div class="autocomplete">
      <div class="input-container">
        <input class="input" placeholder="Some text..." />
        <i class="icon">▾</i>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <div class="list">
          <div class="item">item 1</div>
          <div class="item">item 2</div>
          <div class="item">item 3</div>
          <div class="item">item 4</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="stuff">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</div>
```